# Collectstatic only for certain apps

Tags: python, django, gruntjs

I manage all my static files with Grunt in my Django project. I have setup a gruntfile for my project that gets all js and css files and then concats and minifies them into one file. Those files are copied to a directory named `/static/source` and in my settings I have configured static files like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/build'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PUBLIC_ROOT, 'static')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)
```

All this works fine and I don't have any problem with this. The problem is when I try to use the `admin` app for example. If I add to `STATICFILES_FINDERS` the `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder`, when I do the collectatic process, it also copies all static files from my apps (the source files which I have concatenated and minified with Grunt).

Is there any way to collect the static files only for a certain app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `i` flag of `collectstatic` command to ignore staticfiles from apps.

E.g: `python manage.py collectstatic -i app -i an_other_app`

If you use grunt, you can use `grunt-exec` plugin to run this command automatically.